# How to get queryset in django rest framework for foreignkey?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am working with django rest framework and reactjs library. In django rest framework, I get the queryset of models but for foreignkey I get only url. How can I get the data of that foreignkey when I use axios in frontend..

In models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
class Product (models.Model):
    price = models.CharField()
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
```

After using serializers I get the queryset of `Product` models, but when in frontend I want to get `Product` using `axios` I get a url for `Brand` models... How can I access the `Brand` models from `Product` models?

Comment: can  you please show the response you are getting to your client. Do you mean that the forein key should be nested in the product(response)?

Comment: I use viewset and hyperlink in django rest, then for foreignkey I just get the url. How can I get queryset of this foreignkey in api endpoints?